# Wordpress rewrite rule for specific page and second parametr doesnt work

Tags: pages, rewrite-rules

I have a link like this: https://example.com/page-test/?v=p300 and I created rewrite rule to point new url: https://example.com/page-test/p300/ but it doesnt work.

Just there is redirect to correct website but second parametr "v" is empty.
My code:

```
add_action('init', 'add_test_url');
function add_test_url() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^page-test/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=page-test&v=p300', 'top');
}
```

So first argument pagename is OK and website is redirected to the correct page but second parametr is empty ... why ? Or course after the change I save the settings permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

OK I solved this problem:

New code:

```
add_action('init', 'add_test_url');
function add_test_url() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    add_rewrite_tag('%v%', '(.+)');
    add_rewrite_rule('^page-test/([^/]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=page-test&v=$matches[1]', 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

/// for debug GET value:
function console_log($content) {
    echo "<!-- console_log: " . get_query_var('v') . "-->";
}
add_filter('loop_start', 'console_log', 9);
```

Only thing left is .htaccess redirects from old url to new url:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteRule ^page-test/old_dir/([^/]+)/? page-test/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

In my case I had make a little change for the requests Ajax script and pass variable from GET request:

```
$get_example_v = get_query_var('v');
```